# I dont understand this jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website with two themes, green and blue. The default color is green and then you can click on a button to change to blue, so all text changes to blue.

I searched a bit here on stackoverflow and Think the best resolution is someone that posted this code:

```
function updateStyleSheet(filename) {
    newstylesheet = "Content/css/" + filename + ".css";
    if ($("#dynamic_css").length == 0) {
        $("head").append("<link>")
        css = $("head").children(":last");
        css.attr({
            id: "dynamic_css",
            rel: "stylesheet",
            type: "text/css",
            href: newstylesheet
        });
    } else {
        $("#dynamic_css").attr("href", newstylesheet);
    }
}
```

If I understand correct this should replace a current stylesheet of my website with a new one, getting the same result I want. I have 2 stylesheets; one named `stylegreen.css` and the other named `styleblue.css`.  Where in the code above should I change to make this work, and to put in the html I should add script right? And the last thing is the button to make the change - how should that be?

Comment: here is path "Content/css/" + filename + ".css" you should write "styleblue.css" without content/css etc and it is gonna update your css

Comment: If you don’t understand an answer, you should ask for clarification where the answer was posted, or maybe study the basic technologies used.

Answer (score 2):

It's a function that adds a HTML link tag to header when it is called. In order to put it to work you need:

1 - It requires jQuery. So you have to import jquery library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

2 - Change the path to your css file

```
newstylesheet = "your/path/" + filename + ".css";
```

3 - Call the function giving the name of the css file you want to attach

```
updateStyleSheet("styleblue"); // attach styleblue.css to your page
updateStyleSheet("stylegreen"); // attach styleblue.css to your page
```

Full Example:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="styleSelect">
        <option value="styleblue">Blue</option>
        <option value="stylegreen">Green</option>
    </select>

    <script>
      function updateStyleSheet(filename) {
        newstylesheet = "path/to/css/" + filename + ".css";
        if ($("#dynamic_css").length == 0) {
          $("head").append("<link>")
          css = $("head").children(":last");
          css.attr({
            id: "dynamic_css",
            rel: "stylesheet",
            type: "text/css",
            href: newstylesheet
          });
        } else {
          $("#dynamic_css").attr("href", newstylesheet);
        }
      }

      // It is a plus. It calls the updateStyleSheet function
      // giving the select value as an argument when you change the select element
      $("#styleSelect").change(function() {
           updateStyleSheet($(this).val());
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks that code was awesome. How can i change the value function into instead two link, so they can click on a text saying blue or green.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely simplify your situation since you only have 2 stylesheets.

Assuming they are interchangeable you can just add an ID to the existing default link tag by hard coding it.
*If hard code impractical there are other ways to simply target the correct existing link tag*

```
<link id="site_theme" href="path/to/css/styles_green.css" data-color="green">
```

In JS:

```
/* bind a click handler to some button */
$('#someButtonId').click(function () {
    /* define link tag as jQ object */
    var $link = $('#site_theme'),
        /* current color stored in data attribute */
        currColor = $link.data('color'),
        /* set new color*/
        newColor = currColor === 'green' ? 'blue' : 'green';
    /* modify the href for new theme color */
    $link.attr('href', function (_, currHref) {
        return currHref.replace(currColor, newColor);
        /* store the newColor */
    }).data('color', newColor);
});
```

Above assumes that the colors are in the filenames of the css files.

Subsequent clicks of the button will toggle back and forth between themes